# Is that a negated inner join

Tags: c#, linq

I have seen some times this query. A double from x in list.

Is that a negated inner join?

```
var pupilsWithoutTests = from p in allPupils
            from tp in test.PupilsTests
             where p.Id != tp.PupilId
```

because I can not do

```
var pupilsWithoutTests = from p in allPupils
                         join tp in test.PupilsTests on p.id !equals tp.PupilId;
                         select p;
```

Comment: It is a cross join...

Comment: but from the result it is a negated inner join right?

Comment: Look at left outer join on following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a cross join followed by a filter. I have never heard the term negated join. It is equivalent to `select * from a join b on a.x != b.x`, though, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Did you check generated statement? I suspect it will be `cross join where`.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri yeah, it will be like that. Logically and physically that's equivalent.